# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {{a_n}{\ln{a_n}}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

If $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}\;$  converges,

does the following also converge? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}{\ln{a_n}}$$

When I first saw this problem, it was easy.

So I tried comparison test and limit comparison test.

But i couldn't solve it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we have to assume that $a_n>0$ for each $n$, otherwise $\log a_n$ wouldn't make sense. The problem is that $a_n$ can go to $0$ fast enough to make the series $\sum_n a_n$ convergent, but the fact that $\log a_n$ goes to $-\infty$ can spoil the convergence.

Indeed, define $a_n:=\frac 1{n(\log n)^2}$. Then $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent. 
On the other hand,
$$|a_n\log a_n|\sim \frac 1{n\log n},$$
hence the series $\sum_n a_n\log a_n$ is divergent ($a_n\log a_n\leqslant 0$).

Comment: How can you find a couterexample easily?

Comment: We want $\sum_n a_n$ to be convergent, but with $a_n\to 0$ not too fast because $a_n\log a_n$ will be too small to diverge. Series of the form $\sum_n n^{-1}(\log n)^{-b}$ converge for $b>1$ and diverge otherwise, hence these series are good candidates.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your help!